# Modify one element in each row of a numpy array by column indices

Tags: numpy

I would like to decrement exactly one element in each row of a two-dimensional array, given some indices, one for each row. So basically I want the following to be vectorized:

```
for row, col in enumerate(indices):
    array[row,col] -= 1
```

I can select the elements which I want to modify using `numpy.choose`, but then unfortunately those elements just get copied. Or in other words, something like this does not work:

```
selection = np.choose(indices, array.T)
selection -= 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`integer array indexing`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.12.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html#integer-array-indexing) for a vectorized access and thus assignment -

```
array[np.arange(len(indices)), indices] -= 1
```

Comment: Cool. I guess we can't get rid of the range?

Comment: Nope, we can't get rid of it. Creating such a range array isn't  expensive really.